# Analyzing a person motion data

Tags: algorithm, kinect

I'm in a project of a kinect game and I'm here to ask some help and direction about what should I study (which algorithm, ...) to analyze the points data that the kinect generates in order to detect player's motion (if he is walking or side stepping, etc).

Comment: which sdk are you planning to use ? (eg. official kinect sdk, openni, libfreenect,etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials for [kinect sdk skeleton tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx) if you do a quick search.

Once you're confortable tracking a skeleton you need to look into gesture algorithms. A common one is Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) and on a quick search I see there's [Kinect SDK DTW library](http://kinectdtw.codeplex.com/) out there.

DTW might suffice for training and detecting gestures such as side stepping,etc.
There is more out there, depending on how deep you want to go. Might be worth also having a look at [Nick Gillian's Gesture Recognition Toolkit(GRT)](http://www.nickgillian.com/software/grt). It's pretty general and the [wiki](http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=GRT.ANBC) nicely explains the various algorithms (what algorithm is best suited for what type of gesture/motion)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm focusing on learning detection algorithm. I will wait until tomorrow to accept an answer.